# Auto Change Lead Status based on last activity

Tags: leads

I'm relatively new to coding side of salesforce admin.  We are looking to automatically change the status of a lead if the last activity date is greater than 120 days.

I've tried a few things, but can't see to figure it out.  Any thoughts would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you referring to standard field LastActivityDate. If yes when this is getting updated, I was trying but even when I created a task on lead. It is not getting updated. It is showing blank. Somehow if this gets updated I was thinking for time dependent actions as a solution which will get you free from maintance of batch and scheduler. Please provide inputs to get to the proper solution of this problem.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to write a batch job that runs, probably on daily basis which queries all leads with no activity for specified number of days and then update the status.

As to how to query leads with activities older than 120 days, something like this would work.

```
select id, (select id from tasks), (select id from events), (select id from OpenActivities) from lead where status = 'Open'
```

Then go through each lead, check if there has been any events, tasks or open activities in last 120 days and update lead's status it not so.

Comment: Are you sure you mean batch jobs and not scheduled apex?

Comment: He would need both. Scheduled Apex to wake up at appropriate time and kick off the batch job and Batch Apex to do the actual work.

Answer (score 0):

See [this](https://success.salesforce.com/answers?id=9063A000000ZmmqQAC) and [this](https://github.com/afawcett/declarative-lookup-rollup-summaries) to overcome the limitation on the last activity date for time bound workflow. If you are open to using third party code.